# Laravel's path in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have in JS:

```
$('.' + buttonMulti.data('name')).append('<img src="/uploads/gallery/' 
          + response.file + '" style="max-height: 150px;">');
```

I need some like this one using `{{asset('')}}`:

```
$('.' + buttonMulti.data('name')).append('<img src="{{asset('/uploads/gallery/' 
          + response.file + '')}}" style="max-height: 150px;">');
```

But I have no idea how its make. I always have a problem with path. And after upload img its show me nothing. Because this path

```
{{asset('/uploads/gallery/'+ response.file + '')}}"
```

Can't concat in JS correctly.

Comment: Bro thx for your help ! I again lost this one ' / '  ;))) 

this work 

 $('.' + buttonMulti.data('name')).append('<img src="{{asset('/uploads/gallery/')}}'+ '/' + response.file + '" style="max-height: 150px;">');

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing JS and PHP.

```
asset('path')
```

Is a Blade / PHP function, and you try to concat the parameter using Javascript code. It can't work.

You must use :

```
$('.' + buttonMulti.data('name'))
      .append('<img src="{{ asset('/uploads/gallery/') }}'+ response.file +'" 
                 style="max-height: 150px;" />');
```

I am not sure if `asset()` is triming `/`, look your source code to look at the path. Maybe you will need to add a `/` in your Javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.' + buttonMulti.data('name')).append("<img src=\"{{asset('/uploads/gallery/' + response.file + '')}}\" style='max-height: 150px;'>");
```

The issue i could see was in your double and single quotes that were a bit messed up. Try above approach.

If you want to use double and single quotes as part of your string make sure you escape them or your single quotes are nested inside your double quotes.

If you want to use double quotes inside double quotes then make sure to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

At first use CLI of karabe and run following command to create shortcut of storage.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then follow following link to know laravel default file upload technique.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#storing-uploaded-files

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem
And then, finally check following document to know how to retrieve image link-